# Excel Formula to find specific text but exclude others

Tags: excel

I have an excel file which says

```
Description | 
A
A
A
A
non-A
B
B
B
C
D
E
F
```

I am trying to do a formula which it will only considers those which are **a** so i did this.

```
    =ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*a*",[Description]))
```

But it ended up like this

```
Description | Consider?
    A             Yes
    A             Yes
    A             Yes
    A             Yes
    non-A         Yes
    B             No
    B             No
    B             No
    C             No
    D             No
    E             No
    F             No
```

What I want to achieve is this

```
Description | Consider?
A             Yes
A             Yes
A             Yes
A             Yes
non-A         No
B             No
B             No
B             No
C             No
D             No
E             No
F             No
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, if you have to validate with static data then hardcode it.=IF(H7="A","Yes","No") will give you what you need. Or may be I have not understood yr question.

Comment: Hi no this is not my real data 

For example

A = Implementable / Implementable in progress/ Implementable progressing
non-a = non-Implementable
B= In stalled
C = In Stuck.

So basically only considers those which contains just Implementable

Comment: Remove the * around your a, then it should work. The wildcard (*) allows for any amount of any characters in front or behind your a.

Comment: Tried that but it didnt work too @Luuklag

Comment: I see, use: If(Search("a",description)=1,"Yes","No") This will only take into account descriptions that start with A

Comment: I got some cells which say #value!. did i do anything wrong?

Comment: then probably discription is not a text for those rows.

Comment: I managed to do this: "=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH(""a"",[Description])=1,TRUE,FALSE),FALSE)"

Answer (score 1):

Try...

```
=IF(A2="A","Yes","No")
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
=IF([Description]="A","Yes","No")
```

where     `[Description]` is the range like for example `A11:A22`

Comment: HI managed to do this instead: "=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH(""Implementable"",[Description])=1,TRUE,FALSE),FALSE)"